# Mongoose update after save

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm missing something about callbacks with Mongoose save function.
I am trying to insert a new transaction, then if that is successful, update a user account. The problem, I believe, This cause all people to be updated with the last person's amount. What am I trying to do is update a document after saving another document.

Here is the code. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

```
//find all schedules
SchedModel.find({ Day_Of_Week: day }, null, null, function (err, Sched) {
   if (!err) {
      //iterate through what we find
      for (var key in Sched) {
         if (Sched.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var val = Sched[key];
            console.log("val : " + val);
            var Sched_Descr = day || ' Sched Trans';  
            var this_trans = new TransModel({
                         mID: val.K_Id,
                         mDate: today,
                         mDescr: Sched_Descr,
                         mAmt: val.mAmt
             });
             //insert the new trans
             this_trans.save(function (err, trans) {
                if (!err) {
                   //when we insert new trans, get the update model
                   MyModel.findById(val.K_Id, function (err, Model) {
                      Model.Balance = Model.Balance + val.mAmt;
                      //save model, this update to the last in the list
                      Model.save(function (err) {
                         if (!err) {
                            console.log("updated");
                         } else {
                            console.log(err);
                         }
                      });
                   });              
                } else {
                   return console.log(err);
                }
             });                           
          }
       }
    } else {
       console.log(err);
    };
 });
```

Comment: have you tried findAndModify? It may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: ES6's `let` solves this pretty trivially, just replace `var` with `let` in your original code and it should work.

---

Your `this_trans` and such variables aren't unique in each iteration of the for-in loop. You might wanna wrap it in a self-executing anonymous function scope (`(function(){})()`)

```
//find all schedules
SchedModel.find({ Day_Of_Week: day }, null, null, function (err, Sched) {
   if (!err) {
      //iterate through what we find
      for (var key in Sched) {
        (function(key){       // self-executing anonymous function scope
         if (Sched.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var val = Sched[key];
            console.log("val : " + val);
            var Sched_Descr = day || ' Sched Trans';  
            var this_trans = new TransModel({
                         mID: val.K_Id,
                         mDate: today,
                         mDescr: Sched_Descr,
                         mAmt: val.mAmt
             });
             //insert the new trans
             this_trans.save(function (err, trans) {
                if (!err) {
                   //when we insert new trans, get the update model
                   MyModel.findById(val.K_Id, function (err, Model) {
                      Model.Balance = Model.Balance + val.mAmt;
                      //save model, this update to the last in the list
                      Model.save(function (err) {
                         if (!err) {
                            console.log("updated");
                         } else {
                            console.log(err);
                         }
                      });
                   });              
                } else {
                   return console.log(err);
                }
             });                           
          }
        })(key);
      }
    } else {
       console.log(err);
    };
 });
```